# Are the fibers of a surjective holomorphic submersion $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ all homeomorphic?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Are the fibers of a surjective holomorphic submersion $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ all homeomorphic?

For $n=1$ this means that a surjective entire function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ without critical points assumes each value infinitely often. Is this obvious?

Comment: When $n=1$, we get a covering map of $\mathbb{C}$  by $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected, $f$ must be an isomorphism.  Not sure about higher dimensional cases.

Comment: $f(z)=\int_0^z e^{w^2}dw$ is not a covering

Comment: Is that map a submersion though? i.e. I think it has critical points.  So it doesn't satisfy the hypotheses you stated.  I believe that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a surjective submersion then it is a covering map.

Comment: @freeRmodule: pocryf's example has no critical points by the fundamental theorem of algebra, and is onto, so indeed an example of a holomorphic surjective submersion which is not a covering map.

Comment: Yeah you're both correct I got confused, I thought that surjective+local homeomorphism implied covering map but I'm learning now that's not the case!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no for $n=1$.

**Lemma**: Suppose $f$ is an entire function with $f^{-1}(z_0)$ finite non-empty for some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is surjective.

Proof: By Picard, $f$ misses at most one value. Up to translating $f$ by a scalar (which obviously preserves the hypothesis), we may assume $f$ misses $0$. Then $f = e^g$ for some entire $g$. By assumption, $z_0 \neq 0$, so $\exp^{-1}(z_0)$ is infinite, so by Picard, $g^{-1}(\exp^{-1}(z_0)) = f^{-1}(z_0)$ is infinite, which is a contradiction.

Now take $q(z) := \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n\cdot n!}$ and $f(z) := ze^{q(z)}$. I claim this $f$ yields a contradiction.

Observe that $f(z) = 0$ if and only if $z = 0$. Therefore, the lemma applies, and we see $f$ is surjective. Moreover, we see that not all fibers of $f$ are in bijection: $f^{-1}(0)$ is a singleton, but by (great) Picard (applied to $f(\frac{1}{z})$), $f^{-1}(z)$ is infinite for any other value of $z$.

Finally, let's check that $f$ is a submersion. We have:
$$df = (1+zq')e^q dz.$$
We have $1+zq' = e^z$ by choice of $q$, so this is $e^{z+q}dz$, which is clearly a nowhere vanishing differential.

Comment: Should it be $(n+1)!$ instead of $n\cdot n!$ maybe?

Comment: I think it's correct as written: $q' = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}$, $zq' = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n!}$, so $1+zq' = e^z$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko do you mean $q'(z)=(e^z-1)/z$?

Comment: Did @AlexandreEremenko's comment get deleted?